# Control how many items per page are shown on the activity tab for the mobile theme

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I think it would be nice to control how many items per page are displayed in the activity tab in the mobile theme. Sometimes I have to go back like 20 pages just to check the status of a question I answered a couple hours ago.

The reputation tab has a smaller font and allows scrolling, the activity tab has a larger font, and it shows very few items per page.

Comment: I see this is an old question; just wanted to throw in my support. Would love this for the desktop theme version.